# Python: Getting 10 minute video from traffic camera

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu, video-streaming

I'm using OpenCV with Python to do some computer vision in order to recognize elements in streets. In order to do that, I need to capture some videos from a traffic camera (or street camera). I looked at [camerite.com](http://camerite.com), but there is no way to download videos from the cameras onto my computer.

My question is: can I use some Python code to download the videos? Maybe there's another site that can help? Another programming language?

Any help is apreciated.

*Python 2.7.6, Ubuntu Linux*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Live camera streams use `HLS`. Use the browser's console Network tab to see the HTTP requests and look for a `playlist.m3u8`, copy the URL and use `ffmpeg` to record. Example for a 60 seconds capture:

`ffmpeg -i http://.../playlist.m3u8 -t 60 -c copy -bsf aac_adtstoasc capture.mp4`

Comment: I can't run `ffmpeg`; my ubuntu bash terminal replies `ffmpeg: command not found`

Comment: I also can't find `playlist.m3u8` in the browser's (Google Chrome's) console Network tab

Comment: Well, install it. What format do you see among the HTTP requests? Sort them by type it's easier.

Comment: There is `chunklist_w625474081.m3u8` and `media_w625474081_2231.ts`. But from where should I install `ffmpeg` (when I type it in ubuntu it gives me no sugestions)?

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html and you need to fire up the console before clicking on a cam. You'll then see the playlist.m3u8